# Outline breaks on focus

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where the outline of the element gets broken on focus. I don't know how to solve this, kind of stuck on this for some time.

Note:
I cannot change the height or line-height and also I can't remove the overflow set in the test-header.

It can be solved if I make the test-header the focusable element. But want to avoid that too.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.test {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8dde6;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}

.test-header {
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 70%;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <span class="test" tabindex="0"
        ><span class="test-header">Test big content</span></span
      >
    </div>
```

UPDATE: The answer suggested below by @AlwaysHelping is good, but kind of breaks the ellipsis feature.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are doing `span` and `span`

`display: inline-block` is is not required in this scenario.

See the working example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.test {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d8dde6;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}

.test-header {
  line-height: 30px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 70%;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <span class="test" tabindex="0"><span class="test-header">Test</span></span>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think now I got why I needed that. I actually require the display:inline-block, so that my text-overflow ellipsis can work. right now display inline kind of breaks that feature that I had

Comment: @karthick fingers crossed. I am not sure whether there is an other way except changing the height or line height. Let me know.